# Strange P0420 DTC

Tags: toyota, rav4, p0420

I’ve got an almost new car (Toyota RAV4 Prime with 3000km, 1800 miles). It was in a minor front end accident but everything has been fixed and I’m driving it again, but since the accident I’ve been getting the P0420 DTC. There’s no way an 02 sensor or cat has failed already. I suppose a tiny exhaust leak is possible. But when I erase the code, it comes back immediately and says “permanent” which makes me suspect that something is unplugged. I’ve heard it can be related to the coolant temp sensor, but I am getting a coolant temperature reading on my scanner. Any thoughts out there?[image]

Comment: prob need to check continuity between the sensor and the pins back at the module

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!